# MongoDB aggregate $project to returns a "consistent" object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am using $project so my return object is consistent, but it looks as thou it skips a field if it's not in a record.

Example dataset:

```
{ _id: 1, age: 32, name: "bob",  height: "6 feet" }
{ _id: 1, name: "jim", age: 22, height: "4 feet" }
{ _id: 1, name: "ann", height: "5.5 feet" }
```

Notice Ann is missing "age"

I use this aggregation to get fields returned in same order:

```
db.getCollection('ppl').aggregate([{ "$project": { 
    "name": "$name",
    "age" : "$age",
    "height" : "$height"
}}]
```

But Ann comes back like this:

```
{ _id: 1, name: "ann", height: "5.5 feet" }
```

I really want it to come back with a null or blank 'age'

```
{ _id: 1, name: "ann", age: "", height: "5.5 feet" }
```

How can I do this so ALL my object have ALL the fields I defined in the PROJECT - even if they are missing from the record.???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use $ifNull in your project stage to declare a default.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/EpQsQQ2_TcS